# What should I do to dynamically modify the image's src first

Tags: image

I want to replace the original image with a new one when clicking on a picture.  What should I do?

I directly modified the src of the image, but unexpectedly copied a picture out.

My current practice is to render two images simultaneously, one hidden. When clicked, the current display is hidden and the other hidden.  Is there a better way?

```
Konva.Image.fromURL('./openLight.png', function (darthNode) {
        darthNode.setAttrs({
            x: 400,
            y: 100,
            width: 40,
            height: 40,
            draggable: true,
            id: 'openLight',
            swithLight: 0
        });

        darthNode.on('click', function () {
            darthNode.hide()
            const closeLight = darthNode.getLayer()?.findOne('#closeLight');
            closeLight?.setAttr('opacity', 1);
            closeLight?.show();
            const image = layer1.findOne('#image1');
            image?.hide();
        });
        layer.add(darthNode);
        layer.batchDraw();

    });
```